# How run Odoo 9.0 from source code in Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, odoo

i want to run odoo 9.0 directly from source code in windows 10. I done this:

```
1.- I downloaded source code from [GitHub][1]
2.- I already installed all system requirements (Python 2.7, Node.js, etc)
3.- I already have an postgresql database in AWS (RDS)
```

My problem is when i run odoo.py and i open this url (http://localhost:8069/web/), it show me an empty screen. 
[image: Odoo empty]
Here is my startup code:

```
Python odoo.py --db_host VALID-URL.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -r USERNAME -w PASSWORD -d DATABASENAME --addons-path=addons
```

¿What i am doing wrong?

Comment: you will get some clue from the server log. please paste server log here it will be helpful to resolve your issue here.

Comment: How can i get this server log? I am so new on Odoo :(

Answer (score 1):

- just add the option `--debug` to your command to get debug debug infos

or

- you will find a file named `odoo.conf` (v9 -> v11) or `openerp-server.conf` (v7 or less)

  search for `debug_mode = false` and set them to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had this problem and needed to install node js, and npm less